# How to check date validation in iphone?

Tags: iphone, nsdate

I want to add date into my database ..

and I want to add it in some specific format ..like dd/mm/yyyy

how to check the validation for it?

Like e-mail validation .. I want to check is it in specified format or not?

how to do this ?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

1) What is the input method for your date?

- **If it is thru a `UIDatePicker`, you have nothing to do, the `UIDatePicker` will return a valid NSDate**. I encourage you to manipulate `NSDate` objects and use `UIDatePickers` as date inputs especially to avoid the question of date validation.
- If it is thru a text field, **you can set the `UITextField`'s inputView to an `UIDatePicker`** and you won't have to bother about date validation either as you will obviously directly have a (parsed) NSDate that you can manipulate directly, being sure it is valid.

Then in either case, **use `NSDateFormatter` to convert your `NSDate`** (entered by the user thru UIDatePicker) **to an `NSString`** (to insert in your database).

---

2) If you have a plain text entered by the user thru the keyboard, and can't or don't want to use a `UIDatePicker` (even as the `inputView` of your `UITextField`), **you can convert your `NSString` to an `NSDate` thru an `NSDateFormatter` to check if it returns a non-`nil` `NSDate`** (meaning it is a valid date).

*Note: You may also use `NSRegularExpression` or `NSPredicate` classes to check the format of your string... but you won't have the subtleties of NSDate validation (like checking that 31/02/2011 or 67/13/99 is invalid)*

Comment: okay than ... what should I do if i dont want that general format ? I am using textfield here.. your point 2 right?

Comment: Yes my point 2... or set the `inputView` @property of your `UITextField` to a `UIDatePicker`. Create your `UIDatePicker` instance (either by code or using IB), configure it, set its delegate, then associate its `UIControlEventValueChanged` event to a target & action in your code. In the associated action (= triggered when the user change the date of the picker) you can do whatever you want, like converting the `NSDate` of the `UIDatePicker` to an `NSString` (using an `NSDateFormatter`) and display this string in your `UITextField`.

Comment: suppose user click death date how we validate it   by vinoth